# How to write this java builder with generics to scala?

Tags: java, scala

I'm trying to write this java code in scala, but I am getting a compile error.

```
Document<String, String> doc = Document.<String, String>builder().id("newDocId").score(1d).build();
```

I am trying:

```
val doc = Document.<String, String>builder().id("newDocId").score(1d).build();
```

How do I convert this java generic usage?

I also tried Document[String, String] but I get an error sayingDocument is not a value.

Comment: `Document.builder[String, String]().id("newDocId").score(1d).build()` shoudl do the trick. - If you are going to be using **Scala**, it may be good to learn its syntax first, I would suggest you starting here: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/tour-of-scala.html

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I am familiar with the syntax, I was just confused.  I don't think reading the tour of scala would have helped me on this one!

Comment: @Blankmam Right, I just assumed you were new to the language and suggested the first step. In any case as User said, it should have been straightforward to make the translation if you know both **Java** and **Scala**, so for that reason I made the assumption. In any case, I just hope the comment and the answer solved your problem :)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
val doc = Document.builder[String, String]().id("newDocId").score(1d).build()
```

Scala uses square brackets for generics (and semicolons are optional). Also, the type parameters go to the method, not the object.